# ¿Por qué un código es más eficiente que el otro? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select, eficiencia

Estaba modificando un procedimiento almacenado de sql Server cuando me encontre con este codigo

```
        DECLARE @STR_QRY NVARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @STR_QRY = 'SELECT' 
        + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'A.CODEXAMEN,A.CODPREGUNTA,A.ORDEN,CAST(DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(''str_pregunta'',A.PREGUNTA) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) PREGUNTA,'
        + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'A.DESCRIPCION,A.FLAGREQUERIDO,DESREQUERIDO = CASE A.FLAGREQUERIDO WHEN ''S'' THEN ''SI'' ELSE ''NO'' END,'
        + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'A.PESO,A.TIPOOPCION,A.CODCATEGORIA,V2.DES_LARGA AS DESCRIPCIONTIPOOPCION,A.ESTADO AS CODIGOESTADO,'
        + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'V.DES_LARGA AS DESCRIPCIONESTADO,A.VALORDEFAULT,ARCHIVO,c.codigocalificacion,C.respuesta'       
        + CHAR(13) + 'FROM TB_PREGUNTA_EX A WITH(NOLOCK)'
        + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'INNER JOIN MA_EXAMEN B WITH(NOLOCK)'
        + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'ON A.CODEMPRESA=B.CODEMPRESA AND A.CODUNINEGOCIO=B.CODUNINEGOCIO AND A.CODEXAMEN = B.CODEXAMEN AND A.CODFACULTAD=B.CODFACULTAD AND A.CODESCUELA=B.CODESCUELA'
        + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'INNER JOIN TB_GENERALES V WITH(NOLOCK)  ON A.ESTADO = V.COD_TABLA AND V.ID_TABLA = 1059'
        + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'INNER JOIN TB_GENERALES V2  WITH(NOLOCK) ON A.TIPOOPCION = V2.COD_TABLA AND V2.ID_TABLA = 1060 ' +
        + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.hi_Examen C WITH(NOLOCK) ON A.CodEmpresa = C.codigoempresa AND A.codUniNegocio = C.codigonegocio AND A.CodFacultad = C.CodTipoMod AND ' + 
        + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'A.codescuela = C.CodSubTipoMod AND A.CodExamen = C.Codigoexamen AND A.CodPregunta = C.codigopregunta'-- AND c.codpostulante = ''' + @codpostulante + ''''
        + CHAR(13) + 'WHERE A.estado=''A'' and A.CODEMPRESA = ''' + @CODEMPRESA + ''' AND A.CODUNINEGOCIO = ''' + @CODUNINEGOCIO + ''' AND' +
        + CHAR(13) + 'B.anioacademico = ''' + convert(varchar(4),@int_aniacademico) + ''' AND B.peracademico = ''' + convert(varchar(5),@int_peracademico) + ''' AND' +
        + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'A.CODEXAMEN = ''' + @CODEXAMEN + ''' AND A.CODFACULTAD=''' + @TIPOMODALIDAD + ''' AND A.CODESCUELA=''' + @SUBTIPOMODALIDAD + ''''
        IF @STR_FLAG_ALEATORIO = 'S' SET @STR_QRY += CHAR(13) + 'ORDER BY NEWID()'
        
        PRINT @STR_QRY

        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @STR_QRY
```

y cuando pregunte me dijeron que es para ahorrar codigo ya que la parte final del bloque del codigo:

```
IF @STR_FLAG_ALEATORIO = 'S' SET @STR_QRY += CHAR(13) + 'ORDER BY NEWID()'
```

Es para evitar escribir el codigo 2 veces evitando que la maquina trabaje mas ya que tendria que escribir un select que tenga el **ORDER BY NEWID()** y otro select que no lo tenga.

me dijeron que cuando un procedimiento almacenado se ejecuta primero lee todo el codigo y despues ejecuta y que cuando se trabaja con una pequeña cantidad de datos no se ve la diferencia pero si cuando la cantidad de datos es enorme.

Comment: Un query dinámico sería muy extraño que tenga mejor performance que una consulta común, lo que te han dicho parece totalmente equivocado.

Comment: Al compilar el SP, se analiza todo el contenido para ver que la sintaxis sea correcta, nada más. Están haciendo una consulta dinámica con un par de CONVERT y demás, pero que eso haga más rápida la versión dinámica que un SELECT simple, no es cierto. Lo que gasta revisando sintaxis es varios órdenes de magnitud menor que ir al disco, traer datos, procesarlos y entregarlos, lo que hace la validación de sintaxis despreciable en tiempo. Lo que sí es cierto es que, si uno se va por esa opción, sí es mejor escribir tooodo eso una sola vez (es más mantenible)

Comment: La forma de probar esto es hacer dos versiones del SP, una como está y otra con las consultas select comunes y corrientes. Usar SQL Server Profiler y revisar qué sale en cada caso en el reporte. PD. Que incluyan esos CHAR(13) CHAR(9) hace aún más sospechoso todo porque trasladaron el fin de línea LITERAL en la concatenación de cadenas de la consulta dinámica y ESO NO SE NECESITA.

Answer (score 0):

El ordenar el resultado de una consulta es una operación costosa, en especial en grandes cantidades de datos y por medio de un valor que se está calculando al vuelo.

Sin embargo, el problema más grande de esa consulta es la posibilidad de recibir inyección de SQL, lo que pone en riesgo la integridad de la base de datos. Lo mejor es parametrizar la consulta.

```
    DECLARE @STR_QRY NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @STR_QRY = 'SELECT' 
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'A.CODEXAMEN,A.CODPREGUNTA,A.ORDEN,CAST(DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(''str_pregunta'',A.PREGUNTA) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) PREGUNTA,'
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'A.DESCRIPCION,A.FLAGREQUERIDO,DESREQUERIDO = CASE A.FLAGREQUERIDO WHEN ''S'' THEN ''SI'' ELSE ''NO'' END,'
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'A.PESO,A.TIPOOPCION,A.CODCATEGORIA,V2.DES_LARGA AS DESCRIPCIONTIPOOPCION,A.ESTADO AS CODIGOESTADO,'
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'V.DES_LARGA AS DESCRIPCIONESTADO,A.VALORDEFAULT,ARCHIVO,c.codigocalificacion,C.respuesta'       
    + CHAR(13) + 'FROM TB_PREGUNTA_EX A WITH(NOLOCK)'
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'INNER JOIN MA_EXAMEN B WITH(NOLOCK)'
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'ON A.CODEMPRESA=B.CODEMPRESA AND A.CODUNINEGOCIO=B.CODUNINEGOCIO AND A.CODEXAMEN = B.CODEXAMEN AND A.CODFACULTAD=B.CODFACULTAD AND A.CODESCUELA=B.CODESCUELA'
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'INNER JOIN TB_GENERALES V WITH(NOLOCK)  ON A.ESTADO = V.COD_TABLA AND V.ID_TABLA = 1059'
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'INNER JOIN TB_GENERALES V2  WITH(NOLOCK) ON A.TIPOOPCION = V2.COD_TABLA AND V2.ID_TABLA = 1060 ' +
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.hi_Examen C WITH(NOLOCK) ON A.CodEmpresa = C.codigoempresa AND A.codUniNegocio = C.codigonegocio AND A.CodFacultad = C.CodTipoMod AND ' + 
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'A.codescuela = C.CodSubTipoMod AND A.CodExamen = C.Codigoexamen AND A.CodPregunta = C.codigopregunta'-- AND c.codpostulante = ''' + @codpostulante + ''''
    + CHAR(13) + 'WHERE A.estado=''A'' and A.CODEMPRESA = @CODEMPRESA AND A.CODUNINEGOCIO = @CODUNINEGOCIO AND' +
    + CHAR(13) + 'B.anioacademico = @int_aniacademico AND B.peracademico = @int_peracademico AND' +
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + 'A.CODEXAMEN = @CODEXAMEN AND A.CODFACULTAD= @TIPOMODALIDAD AND A.CODESCUELA= @SUBTIPOMODALIDAD '
    IF @STR_FLAG_ALEATORIO = 'S' SET @STR_QRY += CHAR(13) + 'ORDER BY NEWID()'
    
    PRINT @STR_QRY
    DECLARE @PARAMETROS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @PARAMETROS = N'@CODEMPRESA         nvarchar(100),
    @CODUNINEGOCIO      nvarchar(100),
    @int_aniacademico   int,
    @int_peracademico   int,
    @CODEXAMEN          nvarchar(100),
    @TIPOMODALIDAD      nvarchar(100),
    @SUBTIPOMODALIDAD   nvarchar(100)'
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @STR_QRY, 
                        @PARAMETROS, 
                        @CODEMPRESA,
                        @CODUNINEGOCIO,
                        @int_aniacademico,
                        @int_peracademico,
                        @CODEXAMEN       ,
                        @TIPOMODALIDAD   ,
                        @SUBTIPOMODALIDAD;
```